# How does Instagram check if the users contact are using the application?

Tags: swift, instagram, contacts

In the Instagram app you are able to sychronize your contacts and than the app shows which of them use the application. They are probably using the Contacts framework. Are they fetching the numbers of all contacts and than comparing them in their database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once you allow to give access to your contacts. **Step #1 is to sync your contacts with their server** and they checkout in their database, if any of your contact already using the app (registered to app with that mobile number), they show it for you to better getting in touch with them, otherwise shows you an option to invite them to get started.

Comment: But what if one of the contacts is not registered with the phone number?

Comment: If user got registered with the email and if in your contacts have email linked then it will show.